# python function help - why am I only getting the first number in the argument when I execute the function

Tags: python-3.x, function, args

Here is the code I'v tried, I don't understand why I am getting only the first argument (1) when I execute the program

```
def add(*args):
   total = 0
    for a in args:
      total += a
      return total

sum1 = add(1, 2, 3)
 print(sum1)
```

---

result: 1 
(only the first argument)

Comment: Check your return statement. You're returning the value inside the loop. So, when for loop beings, it takes the 1st argument and add it in variable 'total' and once the addition of 1st argument is done, value is being returned instead of adding 2nd and 3rd argument as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not just getting the first argument. The problem is that your return statement is in the for loop and will execute after the first occurrence of the loop. Unindent your return statement so it runs after the for loop finishes

```
def add(*args):
    total = 0
    for a in args:
        total += a
    return total

sum1 = add(1, 2, 3)
print(sum1)
```